# Spring: Testing view-controllers created with ViewControllerRegistry.addViewController()

Tags: java, spring, junit, controller

This is my first time carrying out junit testing so forgive me if this is a stupid question. The class from my Spring web application which I wish to test is below. The class extends WebMcvConfigurerAdapter to add view controllers.

I just want to test if each of the view controllers maps to the correct view. In every tutorial I've looked at, the test is carried out for a controller which has it's own separate class. it wouldn't make sense for the controllers below to have their own class as there is no logic involved in them. Can anyone direct me for the way i should approach this or give sample code? Do controllers like these which only link to a view even require testing?

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("greeting");
    registry.addViewController("/portal").setViewName("portal");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of testing you are implementing. For unit testing its not necessary since you will be testing Spring internal workings. However for integration testing its necessary so that you can check if your application is wired correctly.

An example of an integration test for your view controllers could be

```
@RunWith(SpringJunitClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MvcConfig.class)
public class ViewControllerIT{

   @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext wac;

   @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login")
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("login"));
    }
}
```